# update and delete in jqGrid not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm experiencing a bad situation with [`jqGrid`](http://www.trirand.net/default.aspx).

I'm using asp.net 4.0 with jqGrid added to the .aspx page. Inorder to `add/edit/delete` the data i'm using a `SqlDataSource` for this purpose.

I've configured default.aspx page like this:

Links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link href="Styles/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in my form i've the SqlDataSource and trirand jqGrid like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_1ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Companies]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Companies] SET [CompanyType] = @CompanyType,[Country] = @Country,[State] = @State,[ZipCode] = @ZipCode WHERE [CompanyId] = @CompanyId"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Companies]([CompanyType],[Country],[State],[ZipCode]) VALUES (@CompanyType,@Country,@State,@ZipCode)" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Companies] WHERE [CompanyId] = @CompanyId">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyId" Type="Int32"/>
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyType" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyType" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyId" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <trirand:JQGrid ID="jQGrid1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" AppearanceSettings-Caption="Company Details"
        AppearanceSettings-ShowCaptionGridToggleButton="true" 
        onrowdeleting="jQGrid1_RowDeleting">
        <Columns>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="CompanyId" Searchable="true" />
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="CompanyType" Editable="true" />
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Country" Editable="true" />
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="State" Editable="true" />
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="ZipCode" Editable="true" />
        </Columns>
        <EditDialogSettings Modal="true" CloseAfterEditing="true" SubmitText="Submit Details"
            Caption="Edit Company" />

        <SearchDialogSettings Modal="true" FindButtonText="Search Company" />
        <ToolBarSettings ShowEditButton="true" ShowAddButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowInlineAddButton="true"
            ShowSearchButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="true" />
    </trirand:JQGrid>
```

Everything looked fine until i've looked into the functionality of what is going on.

At first i've tried to add a row to the `jqGrid`, it worked !.

Then when i try to edit/delete particular row, it ended in vain. edit/update and delete functionalities doesnot work.

Even i've added the rowdeleting in codebehind to check whether i'm getting the appropriate data or not.

I've added the following function using the properties of `jQGrid`

```
protected void jQGrid1_RowDeleting(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridRowDeleteEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

When i place a debugger at the `{` the e i could see the data that is coming when a record is being selected.

When i add a row it adds it to the `jqGrid` and also to the Database. This works great !

Why is it not deleting from the db or even from the jqGrid ?

Is it the fault of the `UpdateCommand`/`DeleteCommand` in the `SqlDataSource` that i've setup ? or do i need to set up additional functionality to implement these things on behalf of jqGrid ?

**Note:** When i could see the data selected in the RowDeleting method in the CodeBehind file i could delete it explicitly by adding some ado.net code. Please post if there is any solution avaliable to do it with jqGrid.

Thanks for your comments/answers posted.

**Edit**

I found the problem when i run the Sql Profiler.

When i edit my colum with form edit, there is not id being passed to it.
Here is what my sql profiler got

```
    exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [Companies] SET [CompanyType] = @CompanyType,[Country] = @Country,

[State] = @State,[ZipCode] = @ZipCode WHERE [CompanyId] = @CompanyId',N'@CompanyType nvarchar

(7),@Country nvarchar(3),@State nvarchar(5),@ZipCode nvarchar(4000),@CompanyId nvarchar

(4000)',@CompanyType=N'pvt',@Country=N'abc',@State=N'def',@ZipCode=NULL,*@CompanyId=NULL*
```

But when i edit a column in jqGrid using Inline edit option i could see my CompanyId being not null.

```
    exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [Companies] SET [CompanyType] = @CompanyType,[Country] = @Country,

[State] = @State,[ZipCode] = @ZipCode WHERE [CompanyId] = @CompanyId',N'@CompanyType nvarchar

(7),@Country nvarchar(3),@State nvarchar(5),@ZipCode nvarchar(4000),@CompanyId nvarchar

(4000)',@CompanyType=N'pvt',@Country=N'abc',@State=N'def',@ZipCode=NULL,*@CompanyId=3*
```

Can some one please point out why is inline query passing id column and why form editing doesnot pass the id value ?

Comment: in your UpDateCommand and DeleteCommand, do you have the `SQL Commands` setup..? perhaps you should create a default command and then override that command with your actual `Sql Commands` it's hard to tell because looking at your `.aspx` markup I can't see what the commands look like

Answer (score 1):

I don't use commercial version of jqGrid/jqSuite myself, but I try guess that you should add `key: true` to the definition of `CompanyId` column. It seems that it corresponds the value `PrimaryKey=true` in `trirand:JQGridColumn` definition of column.

Comment: +1 Thanks now the deletion works but updating doesnot work. Can you please spot ?

Comment: @karthik: Sorry, I wrote that I don't use jqSuite myself. I could recommend you to debug the problem. Do you see some error message? You can start "SQL Server Profiler" to trace all SQL statements which will be executed. Is Update produce some (wrong) UPDATE statement executed on SQL Server or nothing happens? You should debug the problem in some way. I use original open source jqGrid only to know exactly what be done and be able easy to debug every stop.

Comment: I could see inline editing to be working and updating the database but when popup is blown it doesnt work

Comment: @karthik: OK, then updating is do working now. Which "popup" you mean? Do you use both inline editing and form editing in one grid? What is then not working exactly? Is server code on editing is called? Is UPDATE statement executed on SQL server?

Comment: yes i'm using both inline editing and form editing. inline editing works fine, it inserts record to database. While the form editing doesnot work, it doesnot insert record to db nor the jqGrid.

Comment: i could figure out that id is not being passed when i edit a column. check my edit